# AVPlayer unable to play video from NSDocuments Directory on iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, avplayer, ios7.1

I'm trying to get my app to play a video that has been downloaded to the Documents Directory.

My code works when tested on the iOS 7.1 simulator but not on iOS 8.0 devices or the iOS 8.0 simulator. There isn't any error, AVPlayer does not play the video and shows a Black View.

I also checked the Document's folder of my device with XCode's Organizer and the file appears to be successfully downloaded.

Here is a simplified version of my code.

```
// file_path is a string that stores the path to the video file a println of it shows
// "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/83C7837C-59B5-4767-A579-7CE758A93C6F/Documents/og4gr.mp4"
var path:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(file_path, isDirectory: false);
_player = AVPlayer(URL: path);
```

Has anyone else encountered this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would expect to see code with `playerWithURL` or `initWithURL`? Do you call `play` on the `AVPlayer`? Have you checked case-sensitivity of the path?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm using swift so the AVPlayer (URL:path) is the equivalent to initWithURL in objective c. I'm not sure how should I check case sensitivity. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The iOS simulator uses case-insensitive files and paths but devices are case sensitive. I know you mentioned it wasn't working on the iOS 8 simulator but it's worth checking. Beyond that, have you checked the `AVPlayerItem` `_player.currentItem` which contains an `error` property? Can you `NSLog` the `AVPlayerItem` properties and check they are all correct with no error.

Comment: I checked the _player.currentItem, in iOS8 it's nil but in iOS7 the properties appear correctly. `<AVPlayerItem: 0x7ada5f10, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x7ada74a0, URL = file:///Users/Chris/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EBD68AEE-7F40-4635-A4CC-FDD85DEFF627/data/Applications/D700A412-967A-4619-AE73-9EA1131647EF/Documents/og4gr.mp4>>`

Comment: Where is `file_path` coming from? Are you sure the `file_path` content is correct for iOS 8 and the `mp4` exists at that location? If you've checked absolutely everything then I would file a bug.

Comment: I'll need to investigate this more tomorrow. It appears to be an issue with the Document Path. Thank you @RoboticCat I'll update when I figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that the Application Documents Folder Path changes every time you launch the app and I was storing the absolute path of the video file.

According to this article here: 
http://pinkstone.co.uk/where-is-the-documents-directory-for-the-ios-8-simulator/, this is how it is now in iOS 8, which is why while my method worked in iOS7 it was failing on iOS8 devices and Simulators. Thank you @RoboticCat for pointing me in the right direction!